# What are the default mount settings for mount / fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab, default

**What are the default mounting options for a non root partition ?**

The man entry for mount says ...

```
defaults - use default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.
```

... so that might be what we expect to see. But, unless I'm missing something, that's not what happens.

I have an ext3 partition labelled "NewHome20G" which is seen as /dev/sdc6 by the system. This we can see from ...

```
root@john-pc1204:~# blkid | grep NewHome20G
/dev/sdc6: LABEL="NewHome20G" UUID="d024bad5-906c-46c0-b7d4-812daf2c9628" TYPE="ext3"
```

I have an entry in fstab as follows ...

```
root@john-pc1204:~# cat /etc/fstab | grep NewHome
LABEL=NewHome20G        /media/NewHome20G        ext3         rw,nosuid,nodev,exec,users     0  2
```

Note the option settings that are specified in that fstab line.

Now I look at how the partition is actually mounted after boot up ...

```
root@john-pc1204:~# mount -l | grep sdc6
/dev/sdc6 on /media/NewHome20G type ext3 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) [NewHome20G]
```

... so, when the filesystem gets mounted the exec & users options I specified seem to have been ignored.

Just to be sure, I unmount sdc6, remount it and look at the mount options again ...

```
root@john-pc1204:~# umount /dev/sdc6
root@john-pc1204:~# mount /dev/sdc6
root@john-pc1204:~# mount -l | grep sdc6
/dev/sdc6 on /media/NewHome20G type ext3 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) [NewHome20G]
```

.... same result

Now I unmount the partition again, remount it specifying the exec option and look at the result ...

```
root@john-pc1204:~# umount /dev/sdc6
root@john-pc1204:~# mount /dev/sdc6 -o exec
root@john-pc1204:~# mount -l | grep sdc6
/dev/sdc6 on /media/NewHome20G type ext3 (rw,nosuid,nodev) [NewHome20G]
```

... and here the exec option has finally taken effect and the noexec setting has vanished.

Just for interest, I re-mount the partition with the defaults option

```
root@john-pc1204:~# umount /dev/sdc6
root@john-pc1204:~# mount /dev/sdc6 -o defaults
root@john-pc1204:~# mount -l | grep sdc6
/dev/sdc6 on /media/NewHome20G type ext3 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) [NewHome20G]
```

The noexec is back, so it looks very like rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev are the default options which is NOT what man says.

Why does this matter ?

I have a folder full of useful scripts stored on a data disk. Because that disk is mounted noexec 
those scripts won't run, even though they have all been set with chmod 777. I can work round this in several ways but it's disappointing that the man entry seems to be wrong.

Have I missed something obvious here or have the default options in Ubuntu changed from what they were a few versions ago ?

Answer (score 23):

**The manual is correct**. Your issue is that perhaps you didn't account for 3 important details:

- `users` (and `user`) implies the options `noexec`, `nosuid`, and  `nodev`
- *Unless overridden  by **subsequent** options*
- Options **order** matters ;)

So when you use `rw,nosuid,nodev,exec,users` in your **fstab**, the last option, `users`, sets `noexec,nosuid,nodev`, thus disabling your `exec` (and also making your `nosuid,nodev` redundant).

The result, as expected, is `rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev`.

And no, `users` was not ignored, it just doesn't usually show in `mount` listing output. But any user can unmount it and mount it back again. Try it!

```
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ mount /dev/sda6                     # ordinary user
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ mount | grep /dev/sda6
/dev/sda6 on /mnt/mint10 type ext4 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ /mnt/mint10/bin/echo it works       # noexec will deny this
bash: /mnt/mint10/bin/echo: Permission denied
```

`mount` will only show something related to user if `user` (***not*** `users`) is used, and an ordinary, non-root user mounts it, like this:

```
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ mount /dev/sda6         # ordinary user
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ mount | grep /dev/sda6  # it will list current "owner"
/dev/sda6 on /mnt/mint10 type ext4 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,user=rodrigo)
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ umount /dev/sda6
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ sudo mount /dev/sda6
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ mount | grep /dev/sda6  # since owner=root, it won't show
/dev/sda6 on /mnt/mint10 type ext4 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ umount /dev/sda6        # only mounter can unmount
umount: only root can unmount LABEL=MINT10 from /mnt/mint10
```

Also notice that, when using `user` without `noauto`, the partition will be automounted (by root) on boot. So until root unmounts it, no one will be able to unmount or (re-)mount.

That said, I guess you already figured out your solution: ***simply change the order of your options*** and everything will work fine:

```
LABEL=NewHome20G  /media/NewHome20G  ext3  users,exec  0  2
```

Notice how `exec` is *after* `users`. And also `rw,nosuid,nodev` is not necessary. `rw` is already a default, and the others are automatically turned on by `users`

And the result is:

```
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ mount /dev/sda6                  # user mount
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ mount | grep /dev/sda6
/dev/sda6 on /mnt/mint10 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev)
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ /mnt/mint10/bin/echo it works    # exec works
it works
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ sudo umount /dev/sda6            # root unmount
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ sudo mount /dev/sda6             # root mount
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ mount | grep /dev/sda6
/dev/sda6 on /mnt/mint10 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev)
rodrigo@desktop ~ $ umount /dev/sda6                 # user unmount
rodrigo@desktop ~ $
```

Meaning any user, root or non-root, can mount and unmount it, regardless of who previously mounted or unmounted it. And executables works too :)

Comment: Did you mean "...when using `user` without **`auto`**, the partition will be automounted..."?

Comment: @AndreasJ. No, I meant `noauto`. `auto` is already the default behavior, so without `noauto` is the same as with `auto`: the partition will be automounted.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your sentence. It makes perfect sense!