# For fstab in Ubuntu 12.10, what does it show for the Ubuntu UUID?

Tags: 12.10, fstab

I have had to change and unchange this so many times that I want to check what it should be in a new install version.  My fstab is working OK, but I may not have all the correct options written in the file. If you have not modified your U 12.10 fstab file, I would appreciate it if you could give me some feedback by checking gedit /etc/fstab and copying all after your UUID for the Ubuntu partition.  Thanks,  A4Skyhawk

Comment: Copying UUIDs from another system makes no sense at all - UUID stands for Universally Unique Identifier.

Answer (score 1):

It is UUID for your partition. Each UUID can be found with `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`

Comment: Shahverd, you may have responded before I made an edit to my OP.  Please check my question again as your answer doesn't give me the information that I was after.  Thanks, A4Skyhawk.

Answer (score 0):

To show UUID I prefer `blkid`

```
sudo blkid
```

The default entry for fstab will look like:

```
UUID=XXXX  /  ext4  relatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1

UUID=XXXX  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

See also:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

[What are the default mount settings for mount / fstab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182658/what-are-the-default-mount-settings-for-mount-fstab)